# Device to become bluetooth?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, linux-mint, speakers, graphics-tablet

Is there a device where I can plug in non-Bluetooth capable devices so that they would be capable of becoming Bluetooth devices?

I can only find devices that are already Bluetooth by themselves and not really a converter like device.

I know it has to be powered for the device to have Bluetooth capability and I'm more than fine if it will be like that. Better if it could be plugged rather than battery powered.

I highly plan that it could input multiple devices namely - a USB powered keyboard, a USB powered mouse (or a pen tablet) and an IEM earphone.

Also, it is very important that it could work in Debian-based distro Linux OS (as my main OS are Linux Mint 13 XFCE (when it's out) and Linux Mint Debian XFCE).

Thank you and please help.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that your not going to find what you are looking for in a consumer ready state. 
If you have some background in electronics you could wire up a bluetooth module your self.

Examples of Bluetooth Chips/Modules:
If you have worked with microcontrollers before you could link whatever devices you want to an Arduino with a Bluetooth shield:
http://arduino.cc/it/Main/ArduinoBoardBluetooth

Arduinos and other microcontrollers are pretty good general purpose interfaces for other hardware.

http://www.parallax.com/tabid/768/ProductID/550/Default.aspx